# Compile time vs Runtime Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I come across the terms "Compile time" and "Run time" pretty much everywhere when i  
 learn about
azure pipelines.  
However, i still didn't find a clear explanation about them.

I have found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops) in Microsoft's documentation, but it doesn't explain these terms very clearly.

I would be happy if someone could explain these terms in the context of the whole 
run sequence of Azure Pipelines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using YAML Azure Devops pipelines you have your pipelines as code definition. Compile time happens before runtime and you can pass parameters to your YAML before it is compiled (parsed in reality). It will evaluate expressions and replace them in your YAML before even starting any tasks. On runtime, the "compiled" yaml will try for example try to read variables from your Azure Devops pipeline.

Here is an example from Microsoft DOSC:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Expressions are probably the most affected thing when it comes to differences between compile time and run time.

Also a pretty nice article about this:

https://adamtheautomator.com/azure-devops-variables-complete-guide/

Comment: Thanks!   I Saw the article you linked in the end of your answer, and it seems from there that the stages are: Queue time, Runtime and then compile time. is that so?

Comment: That's actually a mistake in the article. Like in programming languages. First is compile-time and after that is Runtime. Here is a pretty good stackoverflow answer explaining the difference with variables in compile time and runtime also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60983879/5392353

Comment: Yep that run time stage should come after the compile stage in the blog post mentioned. :)

Comment: It seems like runtime and compile descriptions are switched in this article https://adamtheautomator.com/azure-devops-variables-complete-guide/ ?